# boost::asio::ip::udp::socket creation - Compilation error - Calling boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(*my_io_service, server_endpoint);

Tags: boost-asio

I am having trouble compiling with boost library with boost.asio.

I am trying to create a `boost-udp` socket from my class constructor. I tried few different things to compile, but still I am seeing the issue.

Does anyone has clue on this issue? Can anyone help me with the mistake, I am doing?

Here is my class:

```
    class NetworkTestToolServer
    {
        private:
            boost::asio::io_service*       my_io_service;
            boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint server_endpoint;
            boost::asio::ip::udp::socket   server_udp_socket;
            boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
            boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint client_endpoint;
        public:
            NetworkTestToolServer(short port);
    };
```

Here is my constructor, I am using (failing at `server_udp_socket`):

```
NetworkTestToolServer::NetworkTestToolServer(short port)
{
    my_io_service = new boost::asio::io_service();

    server_endpoint = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(),
                                                     50002);

    server_udp_socket = boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(*my_io_service, 
                                                     server_endpoint);
}
```

I am seeing the following error:

```
user2@user2-VirtualBox:~/network_test_tool/network-test-tool/build$ make
[ 20%] Built target gmock_main
[ 35%] Built target gmock
[ 45%] Built target gtest
[ 55%] Built target gtest_main
Scanning dependencies of target network-test-tool-lib
[ 60%] Building CXX object app/CMakeFiles/network-test-tool-lib.dir/src/ntt/NetworkTestToolServer.cpp.o                                                                                         
/home/user2/network_test_tool/network-test-tool/app/src/ntt/NetworkTestToolServer.cpp: In constructor ‘ntt::NetworkTestToolServer::NetworkTestToolServer(short int)’:
/home/user2/network_test_tool/network-test-tool/app/src/ntt/NetworkTestToolServer.cpp:34:56: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<boost::asio::ip::udp>::basic_datagram_socket()’
 NetworkTestToolServer::NetworkTestToolServer(short port)
                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:21:0,
                 from /home/user2/network_test_tool/network-test-tool/app/src/ntt/NetworkTestToolServer.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:183:3: note: candidate: template<class Protocol1, class DatagramSocketService1> boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol1, DatagramSocketService1>&&, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Protocol1, Protocol>::value>::type*)
   basic_datagram_socket(
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:183:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/user2/network_test_tool/network-test-tool/app/src/ntt/NetworkTestToolServer.cpp:34:56: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
 NetworkTestToolServer::NetworkTestToolServer(short port)
                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:21:0,
                 from /home/user2/network_test_tool/network-test-tool/app/src/ntt/NetworkTestToolServer.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:147:3: note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>&&) [with Protocol = boost::asio::ip::udp; DatagramSocketService = boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>]
   basic_datagram_socket(basic_datagram_socket&& other)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:147:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:129:3: note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::io_service&, const protocol_type&, const native_handle_type&) [with Protocol = boost::asio::ip::udp; DatagramSocketService = boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>; boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::protocol_type = boost::asio::ip::udp; boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::native_handle_type = int]
   basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:129:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:108:3: note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::io_service&, const endpoint_type&) [with Protocol = boost::asio::ip::udp; DatagramSocketService = boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>; boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::endpoint_type = boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::udp>]
   basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:108:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:86:3: note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::io_service&, const protocol_type&) [with Protocol = boost::asio::ip::udp; DatagramSocketService = boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>; boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::protocol_type = boost::asio::ip::udp]
   basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:86:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:69:12: note: candidate: boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<Protocol, DatagramSocketService>::basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::io_service&) [with Protocol = boost::asio::ip::udp; DatagramSocketService = boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>]
   explicit basic_datagram_socket(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:69:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
app/CMakeFiles/network-test-tool-lib.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'app/CMakeFiles/network-test-tool-lib.dir/src/ntt/NetworkTestToolServer.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [app/CMakeFiles/network-test-tool-lib.dir/src/ntt/NetworkTestToolServer.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1228: recipe for target 'app/CMakeFiles/network-test-tool-lib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [app/CMakeFiles/network-test-tool-lib.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
user2@user2-VirtualBox:~/network_test_tool/network-test-tool/build$
```

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/basic_datagram_socket.html

`udp::socket` doesn't have a default constructor. Your constructor is,

```
NetworkTestToolServer::NetworkTestToolServer(short port)
{
    my_io_service = new boost::asio::io_service();

    server_endpoint = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(),
                                                     50002);

    server_udp_socket = boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(*my_io_service, 
                                                     server_endpoint);
}
```

This is a very poor way of writing constructors. The constructor will call default constructor for every member in the class. In your case, `udp::socket` doesn't have a default constructor. That's why it fails to compile. Only after default construction the statement in the braces block are executed. What you need is `member initializer list`. For more reference, see this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list).

What you want is something like this,

```
class NetworkTestToolServer
{
    using udp = boost::asio::ip::udp;
    private:
        boost::asio::io_service*       my_io_service;
        udp::endpoint server_endpoint;
        udp::socket   server_udp_socket;
        udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
        udp::endpoint client_endpoint;
    public:
        NetworkTestToolServer(short port);
};

NetworkTestToolServer::NetworkTestToolServer(short port)
  : my_io_service(new boost::asio::io_service),
    server_endpoint(udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port)),
    server_udp_socket(udp::socket(*my_io_service, server_endpoint))
{
}
```

It's unfortunate that gcc does not produce very good error code. clang gives much better error,

```
udp_bad.cpp:15:24: error: constructor for 'NetworkTestToolServer' must explicitly initialize the member 'server_udp_socket' which does not have a default constructor
NetworkTestToolServer::NetworkTestToolServer(short port)
```

Try multiple compilers next time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very helpful. How can we determine, if a class has 'default' constructor or not ? In this case, how do we know, whether 'udp::socket' has default constructor or not. Is this documented somewhere ? I could not find about this in boost documentation

Comment: Read the link I posted above. All constructors are listed. There's no constructor taking zero arugments or default arguments. So it couldn't be default constructed. You can try create a simple class like `Class Test { Test(int i) {} };` and check if you can create a instance of `Test` by calling `Test()`. There's a way to determine if a class can be default constructed. For a type `T`, check if `std::is_default_constructible<T>::value` returns true or false.

Comment: I am not trying to discourage you. Boost asio is not a simple library to learn. If you don't understand C++ basics like default constructor, it will be really, really hard. Anyway, ganbade!